# L’expression « poigne de fer » a-t-elle deux significations dans cette phrase ?

Tags: sens

> Quoi de mieux qu’une bonne vieille bataille de boules de neige pendant les vacances d’hiver? Luc et Sophie s’imposent comme les généraux de leurs armées respectives. Ce qui au départ s’annonçait comme une bataille bon enfant devient, **sous la poigne de fer de Luc**, un conflit beaucoup plus sérieux.

Je me demande si « poigne de fer » sert exprès là d’expression à double entente, d'une part en référence à la façon **autoritaire** dont Luc incite les autres enfants à ne se battre que pour gagner, et désignant, d'autre part, une grosse boule de neige qu’il tient **fermement** à pleine main.

Comment: *Poigne de fer* ne peut pas désigner une boule de neige. Il s'agit, pris au sens figuré, de l'attitude autoritaire de Luc dans la bataille, et éventuellement au sens propre, si l'on retient le double sens, de la force exercée par la main qui tient les boules de neige.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

J'y verrais davantage une métaphore filée sur le thème militaire (bataille, généraux, armées, conflit).